# ToolTip Issue in Extjs Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am wondering to see that the tooltip that I am giving inside the Ext window is hiding. It is going back to the window. The code is working fine without a window (It works fine in formPanel). The code and screenshot is attached. I know that the change would be made in target of the tip. But don't know what to give.

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    var btn = new Ext.Button({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        text:'Submit',
        handler:function(){
            new Ext.Window({
                width:600,
                height:500,
                items:[formPanel]
            }).show();        
        }
    })
    var formPanel = Ext.widget('form', {

        width: 350,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        title: 'Account Registration',

        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%'
        },

        /*
         * Listen for validity change on the entire form and update the combined error icon
         */
        listeners: {
            fieldvaliditychange: function() {
                this.updateErrorState();
            },
            fielderrorchange: function() {
                this.updateErrorState();
            }
        },

        updateErrorState: function() {
            var me = this,
                errorCmp, fields, errors;

            if (me.hasBeenDirty || me.getForm().isDirty()) { //prevents showing global error when form first loads
                errorCmp = me.down('#formErrorState');
                fields = me.getForm().getFields();
                errors = [];
                fields.each(function(field) {
                    Ext.Array.forEach(field.getErrors(), function(error) {
                        errors.push({name: field.getFieldLabel(), error: error});
                    });
                });
                errorCmp.setErrors(errors);
                me.hasBeenDirty = true;
            }
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'username',
            fieldLabel: 'User Name',
            allowBlank: false,
            minLength: 6
        }],

        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            dock: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            padding: '10 10 5',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                id: 'formErrorState',
                baseCls: 'form-error-state',
                flex: 1,
                validText: 'Form is valid',
                invalidText: 'Form has errors',
                tipTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<ul><tpl for="."><li><span class="field-name">{name}</span>: <span class="error">{error}</span></li></tpl></ul>'),

                getTip: function() {
                    var tip = this.tip;
                    if (!tip) {
                        tip = this.tip = Ext.widget('tooltip', {
                            target: this.el,
                            title: 'Error Details:',
                            autoHide: false,
                            anchor: 'top',
                            mouseOffset: [-11, -2],
                            closable: true,
                            constrainPosition: false,
                            cls: 'errors-tip'
                        });
                        tip.show();
                    }
                    return tip;
                },

                setErrors: function(errors) {
                    var me = this,
                        baseCls = me.baseCls,
                        tip = me.getTip();

                    errors = Ext.Array.from(errors);

                    // Update CSS class and tooltip content
                    if (errors.length) {
                        me.addCls(baseCls + '-invalid');
                        me.removeCls(baseCls + '-valid');
                        me.update(me.invalidText);
                        tip.setDisabled(false);
                        tip.update(me.tipTpl.apply(errors));
                    } else {
                        me.addCls(baseCls + '-valid');
                        me.removeCls(baseCls + '-invalid');
                        me.update(me.validText);
                        tip.setDisabled(true);
                        tip.hide();
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that ExtJS has a zindex manager, which controls what items are shown when two items overlap.  Hope that points you in the right direction.